# Convert iPhone app to Android app - do I need to know Objective C?

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c

A client asked me to convert his iPhone app to an Android app. I am reluctant to accept this task because I do not know Objective C (I do not develop iPhone apps).

My questions are:
1. Can you convert an iPhone app to an Android app without the knowledge of Objective C?
2. If the answer on Q1 is yes, how should I approach to my client? I mean, I cannot obviously ask him to send me the source code of his iPhone app nor I can install it in the emulator (due to emulator's limitations and due to the fact I do not own an iPhone). So, should I ask him to deeply describe which functionalities he wants or there's a better solution (less tiring for a client)?

In short words, please help with advice :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes.

As an iPhone developer I would not hesitate accept a job to port a good Android app to the iPhone. Depending on the project some source code might actually help. An example of that is when an app needs to sync with a web service. In that case it can be helpful to see the data model, how the app communicates with the service and so on. Data models and application structure is usually pretty similar across languages, given that the application is well designed. These things could probably save you some time even if you're not familiar with the language.

Instead of asking him to describe the app I think you should get screenshots of every screen in the app and perhaps a video of it. That would really help you to understand the scope and the design. If he wants the app to function similarly on Android this is crucial.

Comment: You say that I could understand Objective C at such high level such as communication with remote services?! No offence, but I am rather sceptic because I've come across Objective C and I was quite confused with it (thou it resembled the C I learned at the college).

Comment: Another thing, we all "know" Java (from the college and so on) and I would as well accept porting TO iPhone if I was an iPhone dev and got myself in such situation.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone but I can usually read between the lines even though I'm not familiar with the language. I'm not talking about low level stuff but rather what it needs to communicate and when.

Comment: Objective-C is quite verbose once you know how it's structured. Worst case you could read through one or two tutorials on Obj-C/Cocoa to get the basic understanding of the syntax. I don't even think you'll need that if you're only trying to get the big picture.

Comment: @hjaltij: you're right in advising how to quickly get familiar with an Objective C. I know I could do it in that way. But I cannot say to a client "yes, I will do it, but give me a two-week gap to get familiar with an Obj-C". Would you say something like this?

Comment: I don't think you'll need two weeks. Ask the client to send you the screenshots first and then try to evaluate if you even need to dig into the code. If so, you can ask him for a few extra days to take a look at it before you start.

Comment: You won't be using any code anyway so it's more about the big picture. I recently developed a big iPhone app for a client that is now asking another company to port it to Android. The company in question hasn't asked for any code but they really benefit from having another app that has already dealt with flow, design, UI and UX.

Comment: If you aren't going to ask your client for the app's source code, then why are you worried about learning Obj-C? And since you aren't going to run the iPhone app on an emulator or device, the best you're going to do is work from a functional description and screenshots of the iPhone app. Unless this is a simple app, your Android port of the app won't behave exactly like the iPhone version. Set your client's expectations accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the behavior of the original iPhone app as a specification, and how much time it would take to develop this app for Android purely from spec.

Then source code might not be needed at all.  Or any source code might only be used to scan for the structure or the data model algorithms, etc., which may not require detailed knowledge of the programming language (depending on how well structured and commented is the original source code).

Either the original iPhone developer can send you detailed specs, screenshots, original vector art, etc.  Or you will need to beg, buy or borrow an iOS device to test this app's UI behavior, take your own screen shots, etc., as if this was a reverse engineering project.

Comment: Frankly, it's not achievable to borrow an iPhone device, not to mention that it would take more time to finish a project. The solution with screenshots best suits me. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If the iPhone app was written in Objective C, then no, you can't convert to Android without Obj-C knowledge.

[EDIT: Changed from 'with Obj-C knowledge' to 'without Obj-C knowledge', which was my original intent.]

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. I AM an Android Developer (java) and I do develop Android apps. However, I do not know Objective C and I do NOT develop iPhone app.

Comment: edited my answer. If you don't know Obj-C and the app was developed in Obj-C, you can say no to the job or learn Obj-C as you go, on the job.

Answer (score 1):

### Maybe

Even though Objective-C is generally very verbose, you're going to need a basic understanding of the language as there are quite a few constructs that are quite different than plain C [brackets everywhere]. That being said it is just a super set of C (which is closely related to java), so if you know C or even java you should be able to pick it up in no time, as long you don't have an imediate deadline around the corner, you should be fine.

Watching the first Lecture of the Stanford [CS193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) lectures on iPhone development should get you most of the way there. The lectures are also available on iTunes U.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options for doing an automated conversion from an iPhone/Objective-C project to an Android version...

- [Cocotron](http://cocotron.org/)
- [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/)

I have unfortunately not used either of these so I can't speak to the success/ease of the conversion but I think they are worth a look.  Someone from a well known iPhone game development studio at GDC earlier this month did mention to me that Cocotron worked for them.  They have successfully converted games using it.  GNUStep I had overheard mentioned in casual conversation at a local development meetup in Toronto.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but based on my personal negative experiences with "conversion tools", I would never do a commercial project with such tools. Anyway, I'll bookmark these tools - just in case ;).